# Why isn't my file write method working?

Tags: java, file, io, printwriter, bufferedwriter

This method should write random chars, but it doesn't write anything at all. I'm probably doing something stupidly wrong here, but for the life of me I can't find it.

```
public void writeRandomChunk(String fileName) {
    try {
        File saveFile = new File(folderName + '/' + fileName);

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                             new BufferedWriter(
                             new FileWriter(saveFile)));

        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++) {
                writer.print((char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
            }
            writer.println();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in WorldFile writeRandomFile:\n"
                           + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `PrintWriter` is buffered, you don't need the `BufferedWriter` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any stream (and this applies to most any language), you need to close it when you are done.

Streams are optimized to be fast, and as a consequence, not all of the data you write to them instantly appears in the file.  When you [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close%28%29) or [`flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush%28%29) a stream, the data is written to the file (or whatever other storage mechanism you are using).

In your case, try the following, instead.

```
public void writeRandomChunk(String fileName) {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        File saveFile = new File(folderName + '/' + fileName);
        writer = new PrintWriter(
                             new BufferedWriter(
                             new FileWriter(saveFile)));

        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++) {
                writer.print((char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
            }
            writer.println();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in WorldFile writeRandomFile:\n"
                           + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush() and/or close() the file at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't closed the writer try it in finally.

```
finally  {
  writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always close your stream. try this pattern with writers:

```
PrinterWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PrinterWriter(...);
    // do your write loop here.
} catch (Exception e) {
    // recover from exception.
} finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```